# Getting name of raster in point shp.file Attribute Table using ArcPy? AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to get name of raster for corresponding point if point belongs to raster    and fill column "name"  in   points Attribute Table:

but no names in Attribute Table column "name" of point's shp. file
What can be a problem?

I am getting   error

File "", line 22, in 
    if iR.contains(pnt[0]):

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'contains'

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\1_fire_dNBR" # folder with set of rasters  

inputPoints = r"C:\Users\select3.shp" 

# List of rasters in specific folder
RExtents = [arcpy.Describe(R).extent for R in arcpy.ListRasters()]


#Names:
#RNames = [arcpy.Describe(R).name[:-9]]
RNames = [arcpy.Describe(R).name[:-10] for R in arcpy.ListRasters()]  #  extract  names of rasters
print RNames

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputPoints, ["SHAPE@","name"]) as iCur:

    for pnt in iCur:
        counter = 0
        for iR in RNames:          
            if iR.contains(pnt[0]):

                print iR
                i.value.append(RNames[counter])
                iCur.updateRow["name"] 
        counter =+ 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python string objects do not have a contains method. The correct syntax is

```
if pnt[0] in iR:
```

This will be a case-sensitive search. For case-insensitive search, use pnt[0].lower() and iR.lower() (or upper() if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
for pnt in sCur:
```

should be:

```
for pnt in iCur:
```

Also you do not need this "del iCur" at the end of your script as you are creating iCur within a `with` statement which deals with the release of the cursor.

Comment: Thank you. but Now  i am getting "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'contains'"   in line       if iR.contains(pnt[0]):   How to go away from this?

".